# Problem with Magento 2.3.6 Multi Source Inventory

Tags: magento2.3, multi-website, multi-source-inventory

I have a Magento 2.3.6 installation using multi inventory. I have the following setup:
There many websites. Each website is assigned specific and unique stock. Also, each stock is assigned a unique source. As a result, there do not exist any common sources between websites (each source "feeds" one specific website).

The expected result is the following:
The products are common between websites (global products) and when you browse a specific website, each product should read the stock that corresponds to current website. So, the same product could be available in website A because it reads stock from stock A, and unavailable in website B because it read stock B.

Actual result:
In reality, it seems that magento fails to manage multiple sources in   combination with many websites. When I browse a category page of a website and filter products, it seems that stocks are not taken into account.

Hint:
I checked the records in cataloginventory_stock_item and cataloginventory_stock_status. In both tables the column 'website_id' is '0' for all records. I expected to see records from all websites.  I have also logged mysql queries, as you see in the attached photo the website_id and stock_id correspond to we website 0, despite browser being in another website.
I have attached some photos to help you understand.
Has anyone ever faced the same problem? Any solution? Also, if anyone knows an extension that solves the problem it would be nice.

Thanks in advance

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Show your product edit page (one product), how you manage the source.

Comment: did you ever resolve this without having to upgrade Magento core? We have an identical issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In the MSI context, the tables `catalogintentory_stock_item` and `catalog_inventory_stock_status` are no longer used to provide the information about the products on the frontend. These tables are populated with the data from the default stock only and its default allocated source and will serve to provide the stock data should you disable MSI in your Magento installation.

Check the table `inventory_source_item` for information about the quantity and stock status allocated per product per source. The entries look like this

```sql
mysql> select * from inventory_source_item where sku='24-MB01';
+----------------+-------------+---------+----------+--------+
| source_item_id | source_code | sku     | quantity | status |
+----------------+-------------+---------+----------+--------+
|           2365 | default     | 24-MB01 | 25.0000 |      1 |
+----------------+-------------+---------+----------+--------+
```

Your printscreens show correct inventory and website settings, but my assumption is that you haven't allocated the products to the sources, and that's why you can't see the information properly.

So my suggestion is that you check these resources and give it a try: https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/v2.3/catalog/inventory-product-sources.html and https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/v2.3/catalog/inventory-product-quantity.html.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank for your response Diana. It seems that my configuration is correct. There seems to be a core magento problem here

Comment: no problem, hope you sort this out soon :) cheers!